# Problems transforming data in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, azure-databricks

I've written the function (tested and working) below:

```
import pandas as pd

def ConvertStrDateToWeekId(strDate):
    dateformat = '2016-7-15 22:44:09'
    aDate = pd.to_datetime(strDate)
    wk = aDate.isocalendar()[1]
    yr = aDate.isocalendar()[0]
    Format_4_5_4_date = str(yr) + str(wk)
    return Format_4_5_4_date'
```

and from what I have seen on line I should be able to use it this way:

```
ml_poLines = result.value.select('PURCHASEORDERNUMBER', 'ITEMNUMBER', PRODUCTCOLORID', 'RECEIVINGWAREHOUSEID', ConvertStrDateToWeekId('CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE'))
```

However when I "show" my dataframe the `"CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE"` column is the original datetime string! NO errors are given.

I've also tried this:

`ml_poLines['WeekId'] = (ConvertStrDateToWeekId(ml_poLines['CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE']))`

and get the following error:

`"ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions." which makes no sense to me.`

I've also tried this with no success.

```
 x = ml_poLines.toPandas();
 x['testDates'] = ConvertStrDateToWeekId(x['CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE'])
 ml_poLines2 = spark.createDataFrame(x)
 ml_poLines2.show()
```

The above generates the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the work-around that I got to work:

```
`# convert the confirimedDeliveryDate to a WeekId
 x= ml_poLines.toPandas();
 x['WeekId'] = x[['ITEMNUMBER', 'CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE']].apply(lambda y:ConvertStrDateToWeekId(y[1]), axis=1)
 ml_poLines = spark.createDataFrame(x)
 ml_poLines.show()`
```

Not quite as clean as I would like.
Maybe someone else cam propose a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `ConvertStrDateToWeekId` takes a string. But in the following line the argument of the function call is a series of strings:

```
x['testDates'] = ConvertStrDateToWeekId(x['CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE'])
```

A possible workaround for this error is to use the `apply`-function of pandas:

```
x['testDates'] = x['CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE'].apply(ConvertStrDateToWeekId)
```

But without more information about the kind of data you are processing it is hard to provide further help.

Comment: the source data schema is: 
root
 |-- PURCHASEORDERNUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ITEMNUMBER: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PRODUCTCOLORID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- RECEIVINGWAREHOUSEID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONFIRMEDDELIVERYDATE: string (nullable = true)

Comment: sample data: |       PO-000000185|   1773981|           481|                  DC|  1900-01-01 00:00:00|